# How to simplify if else with four different conditions

Tags: php, logic, slim-3, nested-if

How can I simplifyy this code of mine?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the result of `Carbon::*()` into a variable and call its members.

```php
if (empty($startDate)) {
    $carbon = Carbon::now();
} else {
    $carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat(...);
}
$post->start_at = $carbon;
if (empty($endDate)) {
    $post->end_at = $carbon->endOfDay(); 
} else {
    $post->end_at = Carbon::createFromFormat(...);
}
```

Comment: I have to edit it a little, $post must be saved first before next if else otherwise it's timestamp will change